# T-SQL Group By causing data not to SUM

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that I would like to total the purchases from all Vendors by Year.  However, my results are not coming back summed by vendor like I want.  I believe it is because I have to put IJDATE in the GROUP BY.  Any suggestions how I can fix this?

```
SELECT
    YEAR(ij.IJDATE) AS YearPurchased,
    ISNULL(SUM(ij.IJCOST * ij.IJQTY), 0) AS YearlySpend,
    IJVEND AS Vendor
FROM
    dbo.S2K_IJ ij
WHERE
    ij.IJTYPE IN ('I', 'ID')
GROUP BY
    ij.IJDATE,
    ij.IJVEND
ORDER BY
    YearPurchased,
    Vendor
```

Comment: You need to group by the same expression that's in the SELECT clause (YEAR(ij.IJDATE)).

Comment: I always seem to forget that...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Group By to this:

```
GROUP BY
    YEAR(ij.IJDATE),
    ij.IJVEND
```